# Change colum 'id' to 'userid' in .net core 2.0 authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

This is probably quite easy but I'm new to this and can't find a solution online.
In .net core 2.0 authentication the users table uses ID as the column name for the primary key. I would like to change it to UserID but I can't figure out how to do it.
I've changed the column to UserID in the database and in my custom IdentityUser class but now when I create a new record an error message says

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'Id'.

Answer (score 0):

I manged to find the answer :-

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Domain.Models.Member>().Property(up => up.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    }
```